# jquery is not loading properly on server within localhost working fine

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This snippet of code is working good on local host but not working on server. After multiple refresh j query is loading properly then works as expected. jQuery is loaded async on page load and taking more time to load the page.

how to make jQuery to load properly without page refresh and how to reduce load time for all the scripts which are at end of page

```
<noscript id="async-styles">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/star-rating.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.0.1/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

</noscript>

<script> // The CSS mentioned in "async-styles" will be loaded and styles will be applied.
    var loadDeferredStyles = function() {
        var addStylesNode = document.getElementById("async-styles");
        var replacement = document.createElement("div");
        replacement.innerHTML = addStylesNode.textContent;
        document.body.appendChild(replacement)
        addStylesNode.parentElement.removeChild(addStylesNode);
    };
    var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
    if (raf) raf(function() {
        window.setTimeout(loadDeferredStyles, 0);
    });
    else window.addEventListener('load', loadDeferredStyles);
</script>

<script async src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" onLoad="loadOtherScripts();"></script>
<script>
    function loadScript(src) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var s;
            s = document.createElement('script');
            s.src = src;
            s.onload = resolve;
            s.onerror = reject;
            document.head.appendChild(s);
        });
    }

    function loadOtherScripts() {
        loadScript('js/moment.min.js')
      .then(function() {
      Promise.all([ loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js'),loadScript('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'),loadScript('js/daterangepicker.js'),loadScript('js/star-rating.min.js'),loadScript('js/sidebar.js'),loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.9.1/jquery.tablesorter.min.js'),loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.0.1/js/bootstrap-switch.js')]).then(function () {
        intialFunction();
      }).catch(function (error) {
    //  console.log('some error!' + error)
      })
      }).catch(function (error) {
    //  console.log('Moment call error!' + error)
      })
      }
</script>
```

Comment: What you appear to be doing is very strange. What are you trying to achive with this code? http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: It's probably because of the async loading. It obviously is faster on localhost then on a remote server. The reason it worked on refreshes is probably because of cashing or luck. Your code gets executed before the loading is finished. Is that 100k of minified jQuery code really so problematic that you need to load it async?

Comment: It is loaded async as you can see in code

Comment: @ThomasEdwards bro i have a page which displayed user details and it contains form which is displayed on click update button. with in form two drop downs are present, second is dependent on first. code for drop-down is written in ready function. within server after clicking update button first drop-down is displayed but second drop-down is not displayed but working as expected in local host

Comment: More Over scripts are not loaded properly

Comment: Why are your scripts in a `noscript` tag?

Comment: I don't know exact reason why scripts are in noscript tag this code is written by other person i need to rework on it.

Answer (score -1):

instead of loading all that needed one by one we can minify and bundle it and load in one go. This will reduce the size and network round trip for each script.